# How to get the Size (KB) of UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage

I am getting Image from `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`.

```
UIImage *originalImage = (UIImage*)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

I want to get the size of Image in Kb.

Comment: The size of the internal representation or the size of the file on disk?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815292/how-to-get-size-of-uiimage-size-like-500-kb-600-kb-etc

Comment: @shashank : no Im afraid not

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
    UIImage *originalImage = (UIImage*)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(originalImage, 1); //1 it represents the quality of the image.
    NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%d",[imgData length]);
    imgData = nil;
```

Comment: Looks expensive!  You are creating a duplicate on-disk representation just to get its size!

Comment: @trojanfoe any other solution?

Comment: @AmiriDev if it came from disk then you can get the url from the dictionary passed with that delegate call and then use `NSFileManager` to get file information.  I am only guessing though...

Answer (score 0):

I think the op's `size (kb)` is the memory size of `originalImage`, right?

Check out the usage about `malloc_size` under the ARC refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761969/checking-the-size-of-an-object-in-objective-c).

```
#import <malloc/malloc.h>

NSLog(@"Size of %@: %zd", NSStringFromClass([originalImage class]), malloc_size((__bridge const void *)originalImage));
```