# How to get the size of image & video from UIimagepicker in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am picking a image & video using UIImagePickController.I want to ge the size of that image or video so that i can restrict user for uploading large files.I am trying following code for image but it gives me wring data.Size of image is 1.5MB but it always show 13.6 MB.Below is the code for that.

```
UIImage *originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(originalImage);
NSLog(@"%f",(float)[imageData length]/1024.0f/1024.0f);
```

Comment: may be this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815292/how-to-get-the-compressed-file-size-of-an-image-received-from-uiimagepickercont) helps you

Comment: NSLog(@"MyImage size in bytes:%i",[UIImagePNGRepresentation(originalImage) length]);

Comment: Does not give accurate result. @SamraanKhaan

Comment: Are you sure, your image is in .png format ?

Comment: No it can b jpg as well

Comment: How are you determining the 1.5 megabyte image size? Photos saves in JPEG by default, which is much much better at compressing photos. If you're using PNG instead as your code does I'd expect a lot bigger number.

Comment: I am determing by checking the details of image it shows me the 1.5 mb